# Database per-user connection for spring hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm working on a Spring JPA/Hibernate project which must use a database user's connection for persistence.

In fact, every user has their own Oracle DB connection and I must use it in the app to know who accesses and writes to my database.

How can I use a different db connection with Hibernate instead of using a single app connection (in the applicationContext datasource)?

Comment: You probably should consider proxy authentication instead, as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066295/switching-users-on-a-jdbc-connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about `AbstractRoutingDataSource` and my old question
[AbstractRoutingDataSource change map in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30273593/abstractroutingdatasource-change-map-in-runtime)

**Session listener:**

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    @Autowired
    DataSourceMap dataSourceMap;
    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
        System.out.println("tworzenie sesji");
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
        System.out.println(httpSessionEvent.getSession().getId());
        dataSourceMap.removeSource(httpSessionEvent.getSession().getId());
    }
}
```

**Routing:**

```
@Component
public class CustomRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource{
    @Autowired
    DataSourceMap dataSources;
    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        //setDataSources(dataSources);
        afterPropertiesSet();
        System.out.println("test");
        if( SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()!=null) {
            HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)
                    RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
            return request.getSession().getId();
        }

        return "auth";
    }
    @Autowired
    public void setDataSources(DataSourceMap dataSources) {
        System.out.println("data adding");
        setTargetDataSources(dataSources.getDataSourceMap());
    }

}
```

**Map:**

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "singleton")
public class DataSourceMap {
    private Map<Object,Object> dataSourceMap;
    public DataSourceMap()
    {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:mem:AZ;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("sa");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("");
        dataSourceMap=new HashMap<Object,Object>();
        dataSourceMap.put("auth",dataSourceBuilder.build());
    }
    public void addDataSource(String session,DataSource dataSource)
    {
        this.dataSourceMap.put(session,dataSource);
    }
    public Map<Object,Object> getDataSourceMap()
    {
        return dataSourceMap;
    }
    public void removeSource(String session)
    {
        dataSourceMap.remove(session);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I already read this article but I have some problem to make it works.
Do you have a code/project example to help me ?
Thank you.

Comment: Thank's @seti, it works !
But I have the same problem as you, I can't close the datasource pool when the session is closed. I remove my datasource in the dataSourceMap with the sessionDestroyed method but the connections still active in the  database.

Comment: I add my old code from 10 month ago. You store user databases in database or you now all databases on runtime?

Comment: It works ! I'm just using `OracleDataSource` instead of a `dataSourceBuilder` because I had some problems with the connection pool. It's OK now. Thanks, I should buy you a drink for all the time you saved me ;)

Comment: I can't because I don't have enought "reputation"...
I think it will be better to map the datasource with the sessionregistery than the http request sessionId